# Most common Apache and PHP configuration for portable Web Applications

Tags: php, apache, operating-system

I always create web application using PHP but I always distribute and deploy my works to different kinds of server platforms and web server configurations. Thus I always encounter problems in deployment because some features are enabled and others are disabled. And my question, is there a standard web server configuration that is commonly used by most of web servers worldwide? covering the aspects of reliability, security and maintainability?

Comment: Apache 2* php 5* you should have a deplpyment script that checks for issues.

Answer (score 1):

There are defaults typically for both the PHP.ini and the apache conf file, but it would vary depending on the version of PHP and Apache running. Do you develop for a set verserion like 5.2.x (PHP) and v.2.0.x or 2.2.x Apache? Knowing this would help ID what the typical defaults would be (like registered globals, etc.)